# Using log4net in F# as a singleton separate class

Tags: f#, log4net

I've seen a few posts about implementing log4net using C# and F# - but I am wanting to implement it as a singleton in a separate class ( so I can call from anywhere )

I am loosely following [this post](https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/).  I just think my translation from C# to F# is a bit behind.

I set up the log4net.config and run the following code at the start of my console app

```
namespace MyNamespace

open System.IO
open log4net.Config

module LoggerConfigure = 
    let configureLogging() = 
        FileInfo("log4net.config")
        |> XmlConfigurator.Configure
        |> ignore
```

The following ( from the link above ) is C# and I want it to be an F# class that can be called as a singleton.

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

My primary quwation is - I'm a bit stuck converting that to an F# class.  How do I do that?.  Any ideas you have around the whole concept is appreciated as well.

Comment: a module is effectively a static class.

Answer (score 1):

There may be cases where a more sophisticated handling of singletons is needed, but I believe that standard global `let` declaration in an F# module would work well enough.

You just need to make sure that the configuration code is run before the `log` value is accessed, which you can do by making that call as part of the let binding that defines `log`:

```
module LoggerConfigure = 
    let configureLogging() = 
        FileInfo("log4net.config")
            |> XmlConfigurator.Configure
            |> ignore
        log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
            (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)
    let log = configureLogging()
```

Or if you prefer to put everything in a single expression:

```
module LoggerConfigure = 
    let log =
        FileInfo("log4net.config") |> XmlConfigurator.Configure |> ignore
        log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
            (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)
```